# Defining a View inisde the shared/EditorTemplete folder is not working on my asp.net mvc-4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application. now i have the following view model class:-

```
public class ServerJoin : CreateResource,  IValidatableObject
{
    public Server Server { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

and the CreateResource class is as follow:-

```
 public class CreateResource
    {
        public CreateResource()
        {
            this.operation = new Operation5();
            this.createAccount = new CreateAccount();
        }
        public Operation5 operation { get; set; }
        public CreateAccount createAccount { get; set; }

    }
    public class Operation5
    {
        public Operation5()
        {
            this.Details = new Details4();
        }
        public Details4 Details { set; get; }
    }
    public class Details4
    {
        public Details4()
        {

            this.RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD = new List<RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD>();
        }
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string RESOURCENAME { set; get; }
//code goes here....
```

now i have the following inside a Main view :-

```
 @model S.ViewModels.ServerJoin
 @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.operation.Details)
```

and i have created a view under the Shared/EditorTemplete folder named `Details4.cshtml`:-

```
@model S.ViewModels.Details4
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RESOURCENAME)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RESOURCENAME)
```

now i was expecting that inside my MAIN view the following  `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.operation.Details)` should render the view named `Details4.cshtml` defined inside the EditorTemplete  ? but it did not? so can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Shared/EditorTemplates` not `Shared/EditorTemplete`.